# jQuery creating elements - another .attr() vs .prop() question

Tags: jquery, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Given the new [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/.prop/) method in jQuery, which is the preferred way to *create* a new element with particular fields, e.g. a link:

1. `$('<a>').prop('href', '...');`
2. `$('<a>').attr('href', '...');`
3. `$('<a href="...">');`

I've always tended to use #2, but it's unclear whether a *new* element being put in the DOM shouldn't now use #1 instead.

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE.  The linked question is primarily about property and attribute **getters**. This question is exclusively about **setters**, and even more specifically about their application to a newly created DOM element. The answer to this question is only obliquely addressed on the linked page.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone you could vote to reopen, if you have enough rep, but I did get the answer I was looking for (below)

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak I have my answer too. Just leaving a tip for posterity in lieu of sufficient rep to reopen (3K I think).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would go with `attr()` in that case. You're creating a new `<a>` element and setting its `href` *HTML attribute*, so it would make sense to emphasize that.

However, since the `href` attribute directly maps to the `href` DOM property, using `prop()` would have the exact same result.

Let's take another example, more relevant to the differences between `attr()` and `prop()`: suppose you want to set the `class` attribute of the `<a>` element instead of its `href`. The sample code in your question becomes:

1. `$('<a>').prop('className', '...');`
2. `$('<a>').attr('class', '...');`
3. `$('<a class="...">');`

IMHO, (2) and (3) make one's intent clearer than (1). The fact that there cannot be a DOM property named `class`, because that token might be a reserved word in the host language, is at best an implementation detail. The `class` HTML attribute is usually what we're thinking about in that context.

Of course, there are situations where the opposite is true, e.g. when working with "boolean" HTML attributes like `checked` or `disabled`. In that case, it would be more robust to set the strongly-typed DOM property instead of creating the less well-defined HTML attribute.

Comment: +1 For a detailed explanation instead of _why_ instead of just a "because I said so" answer

Answer (score 7):

I usually would create the a tag like so:

```
$('<a>', {href: '...'});
```

Adds as many attributes to the element at the start. (yes `attributes`, not properties)

So you can do the same thing for items like inputs:

```
      $('<input>',{
                name: 'some_name',
                id: 'some_id',
                value: item_value,
                readonly: 'true',
                style: 'background: #eee;',
                size: 15
            });
```

Or actual divs:

```
      $('<div>',{
                id: 'some_id',
                text: 'this will be inside the div'
            });
```

Here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/mbjgd/

**EDIT**
From my comment below:

The reason for this is because when you create the item, you are creating it by setting it's attributes, later on those attributes become meaningless when they are changed by something like javascript, so at that point you have to use the object's properties to get the real solution that you might be looking for.

Comment: interesting - I wasn't aware of that syntax.

Comment: i use it all the time for defining many object like inputs for example: `$('<input>',{
                    name: item.name,
                    id: item.id,
                    value: item_value,
                    readonly: 'true',
                    style: 'background: #eee;',
                    size: 15
                });`

Comment: @Alnitak, i edited by post to show you better. i will add a fiddle as well

Comment: thanks, although we're still missing a decent rationale for why attributes rather than properties in this case, when after the fact people now mostly appear to advise the latter.

Comment: @Alnitak, this is bc when you create the item, you are creating it by setting it's attributes, later on those attributes become meaningless when they are changed by something like javascript, so at that point you have to use the object's properties to get the real solution that you might be looking for

Comment: Another advantage to this method, as far as I can tell, you can use **reserved words** for the attributes, e.g. `class: 'some-class', type: 'text'`. I know for .prop() at least you'd need to use className instead of class.