# .attr('checked') will not tell me that the radio button is checked even when it is

Tags: jquery, radio-button, attr, checked

my first question!...  I'm a uni student trying to make a simple, multiple-choice quiz.  I've almost finished it (the bare bones of it) but can't calculate the final score of the user.  The quiz can be see online at:  [eyeballs.site88.net](http://eyeballs.site88.net/)  (this is just the quiz so there's no other distracting code).

I thought this approach would be simple:
1. start with a score of 0.
2. when the "Answers" button is clicked on by the user, (for each question) check to see if the radio button next to the correct answer is checked
3. if it is, add 1 to the score
4. if it's not, do nothing
5. after the final question has been checked, announce the score to the user

All of the code seems to work just fine, except for the .attr('checked') part.  I replaced this with .val() & the score added up just fine, & was announced at the end.  However, even when the correct answer is checked, 1 will not be added to the score.  I have seen .attr('checked') in action before - it checked to see if a checkbox "Same as Above" had been checked:  if it was checked a div slid out of view; if it was unchecked the div slid back into view.  But I can't get anything to happen!

The following code is a simplified version (just Question 1, with only 2 answer choices):

HTML

```
<form action=”xxxxx” method=”post” class=”quiz”>
    <ul>
        <li  class="quizQuestionAndAnswer" id="question1" >
            <dl>

                <dt class="quizQuestion"><strong>1. An animal with horizontal, rectangular pupils is a:</strong>
                </dt>

                <dd class="quizAnswers">

                    <div>
                         <input type="radio" name="question1Answer" id="question1answerA"  value="goat"     >
                         <label for="question1answerA">goat</label>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question1Answer" id="question1answerB" value="elephant" >
                        <label for="question1answerB">elephant</label>
                    </div>

                </dd>

            </dl><!--end question1-->
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()  {


            var score=0, 
                $questionAndAnswer=$('.quizQuestionAndAnswer');

    $questionAndAnswer.on('click', '.answersQuizButton', function()   {

        if(  $('#question1answerA').attr('checked')   )   {
            score=score+1;
        }  //end if
        if(  $('#question2answerC').attr('checked')   )   {
            score=score+1;
        }  //end if

        alert(score);

    });  //end on (click)

});  //end ready
</script>
```

I'd very grateful for any suggestions!
:)  uphillfun  ps:  I'm using jQuery 1.11.0, & Firebug console does not show any errors!

Comment: Just curious - Where is `$questionAndAnswer` defined?

Comment: Btw, [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6432259/1223045) will give you the reason why it's not working

Comment: apologies, I'm new to this (& nervous!).  I've just edited the question to include the variable you questioned.  It is in the original code.  :)

Comment: Np, do check the link I provided which tells you why `.attr()` isn't working, but `.prop()` will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use instead:

```
if($('#question1answerA').prop('checked'))
```

Comment: `prop` returns a boolean here: it makes no sense to compare it with `true`.

Comment: I tried .prop('checked') instead & it worked perfectly!  I have not heard of this function before (I'm a uni student new to jQuery).  Are you able to tell me why it worked?  According to my textbook .attr('checked') should work (there's an example in the textbook but working with a checkbox, not a radio button).  :)

Comment: You try to use a custom attribute named "checked" but is not exist in radio element. Hope it helps:)

Comment: @Alexandros Thanks so much! I would like to "accept" your answer but don't know how to do that!.....  edit:  just figured it out!  Victory on my very 1st question, thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

Others ways to check if the box is checked

```
$('#question1answerA')[0].checked
```

```
$('#question1answerA:checked').length
```

```
$('#question1answerA').is(':checked')
```

Comment: those suggestions are a little above my head, as I'm a newbie, but I'll definitely check them out! thanks  :)