# jquery: setting radio inout as checked

Tags: jquery

This is so basic, but I cant get it.

On a donation form,  people select either pre-set amountoptions or 'other'. If they choose 'other', the 'other' radio button must be activated even if a pre-set was selected.

HTML:

```
<label>
<input type="radio" name="x_ccPayment" class="required" title="*" 
    value="120" data-payment="once" />
$120</label>


<label>
<input type="radio" name="x_ccPayment" class="required" title="*"
    value="50" data-payment="once" />
$50</label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="x_ccPayment" class="required" title="*"
    value="-99" data-payment="once" />
Other:</label>
<input type="text" name="x_ccPayment_other" id="other_once" style="width: 100px;" value="" onKeyUp="checkNumericInput(this)"  data-payment="once" class="form-control" />
```

JQUERY:

```
 $("#other_once").keyup(function(){
    var other_once =  $("#other_once").val();
    if (other_once !=='') {
        $("input[name=x_ccPayment]").removeAttr('checked'); // deselect other options
        $("input[name=x_ccPayment][data-payment=once][value=-99]").attr('checked','checked');  /auto-select the 'other' radio
    }

 });
```

when I look at the Dev tools, i see the radio is `checked` correctly, but this does not show on the screen.

Comment: Don't use `.attr` to modify properties.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432246/radio-buttons-and-attrchecked-checked-does-not-work-in-ie7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.removeAttr()` and `.attr()` for the checked *property*. Use `.prop()`:

```
$("input[name=x_ccPayment]").prop('checked',false); // deselect other options
$("input[name=x_ccPayment][data-payment=once][value=-99]").prop('checked',true);
```